# Calculate the height then add inline css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a set of list items which have differing heights depending on their contents. The list items are positioned absolutely, and for this to work correctly I need to calculate their individual heights and apply it inline with css.

```
<ul id="grid">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to do this with jQuery, but I'm getting something wrong - would anybody be kind enough to help please?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid li").each(function()) {
           $(this).css('height', height() + 'px');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid li").each(function() {
           $(this).css('height', $(this).height() + 'px');
    });
});
```